# Splashscreen not appearing when I run .jar file in dist Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm having a problem with my splash screen in jframe app ... I managed to create one that works just fine when I run it in netbeans, but when I close  netbeans and try to run the .jar file on itself (dist folder), the program loads with no splashscreen. Any idea of how I can get the splashscreen to appear when I run .jar file?